# why does php mysql update returns a success but never updated the column?

Tags: php, android, mysql

my basic goal is to update a single row and if it is successful it will insert some data in different table.

here is my query

```
$upd = mysql_query("UPDATE request_tbl SET status='1' WHERE sender='$user_id' AND reciever='$id'", $con);

if($upd){
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact_tbl (id, friend_id) VALUES ('$user_id', '$id')", $con);
    $result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact_tbl (id, friend_id) VALUES ('$id', '$user_id')", $con);
    
    if($result && $result2){
        $jsonresult = $myFunctions->jsonRequest("Sent Request");
    }
    else{
        $jsonresult = $myFunctions->jsonRequest("Failed Request");
    
    }

}
```

note: the scenario is i am updating data to the webserver using android app,

when i try to test the query from using this.

http://----/-----.php?req=accept&user-id=5&id=1

i get a success message and updates, and insert the data in the database. However when i try to send the request from the app it returns a success message and inserts the data, that means that the update was successful but in the database it was never update.

i also tried to change the data type of the column status to int or varchar but still with the same effect, it is weird the insert was excuted but the update was never happened or it was?

**EDIT ! ! !**
i did try all the recommended solutions like mysql_affected_rows() > 0 and echoing the query but with no luck.. as everyone recommends/insits :) i will try to convert the query into PDO or mysqli thanks for the help everyone.

**EDIT 2 ! ! ! **

i tried to to convert my queries to PDO
here is my code

```
    $upd = $con->prepare("UPDATE request_tbl SET `status`='1' WHERE `sender`='$user_id' AND `reciever`='$id' AND `status`='0'");

try{
    $upd->execute();
    $result = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO contact_tbl (id, friend_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $result->bindParam(1, $user_id);
    $result->bindParam(2, $id);
    $result2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO contact_tbl (id, friend_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $result2->bindParam(1, $id);
    $result2->bindParam(2, $user_id);
    
    try{
        $result->execute();
        $result2->execute();
        $jsonresult = $myFunctions->jsonRequest("Sent Request");
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $jsonresult = $myFunctions->jsonRequest("Failed Request");
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $jsonresult = $myFunctions->jsonRequest("Failed Request");
}

echo $jsonresult;
```

but i recieve the same result, whenever i try it using the url method the update and insert are successful with the correct value, but when i do it with the app the update and insert returns successful and the insert have the correct value but the update did not change the column im changing..

Comment: echo  the query you are making, run it inside sqlYog, it might be firing any error

Comment: you really should not be writing code like this John. First, you are using parameters, not a POST. Second, you are using mysql_* functions, deprecated. Your data can and will endure sql injection attacks. In the above code, it can have 2nd order sql injection. In cases of select stmts, surely done the same way, your tables can be easily dropped. Instead, use mysqli or pdo with prepared statements.

Comment: @drew thank for the infos, but im fully aware that i should use POST method but i did it that way so that i can test it easily and will change it when all my functions/features are working..

Comment: fair enough. Those that follow might not. Plus get onto the pdo bandwagon !

Comment: The two queries in the `if` block can be made into one: `VALUES (...), (...)`. Also, you should use something like `PDO` or `MySQLi`. The `mysql` driver is very old and it is not recommended that people use it.

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_affected_rows()` to check how many rows were affected. Try this,

```
if(mysql_affected_rows()){
    // your stuff here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that values of `$user_id` and `$id` getting on the current page you are in.

Hopefully, you passed the user id variable as `user-id` and retrieved as `$_GET['user-id']`.

If its perfect then, `echo` both queries and run the printed query on `phpmyadmin` manually. That will through the erroe

```
echo $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact_tbl (id, friend_id) VALUES ('$user_id', '$id')", $con);
echo $result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact_tbl (id, friend_id) VALUES ('$id', '$user_id')", $con);
```

more over `mysql_query` has been deprecated. Those functions will be no more exist. Try `PDO` or `MySQLi`

Comment: im on my way learning PDO, but back to the issue, the inserted data was the $user_id and $id which is also the value in WHERE on the update, and when they are inserted they have the correct value im expecting, the thing is the update query never change the column im trying to change.

Answer (score 0):

try this folk, use mysql_num_rows(). mysql_affected_rows() give you a nums of rows afected by the last query executed. and you know how manny rows are afected. Hope this can help you

```
$upd = mysql_query("UPDATE request_tbl SET status='1' WHERE    sender='$user_id' AND reciever='$id'", $con);

$NumsRowsAfected = mysql_affected_rows();

    if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
       $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact_tbl (id, friend_id) VALUES     ('$user_id', '$id')", $con);
       $result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact_tbl (id, friend_id) VALUES ('$id', '$user_id')", $con);

       if($result && $result2){
         $jsonresult = $myFunctions->jsonRequest("Sent Request");
       }
       else{
         $jsonresult = $myFunctions->jsonRequest("Failed Request");

       }
    }
```